# How to parse a map from config using TypeSafe in JAVA?

Tags: java, config, typesafe

I've config like this with a map PurchaseDates :

```
AppConfig{

PurchaseDates:{"PURCHASE":"ENTITLEMENTDATE","STOCK_SUBSCRIPTION_PURCHASE":"SSENTITLEMENTDATE"}

}
```

How do I parse this PurchaseDates map in JAVA code using TypeSafe Config ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeSafe has built-in support for reading maps from config , so no special handling is needed .

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the cleanest way to do this, one thing you can do is to store your map as a string in the config, retrieving it from config as a string and then parse it as a map using any generic json utility. Something like

```
    AppConfig{
         PurchaseDates:"{\"PURCHASE\":\"ENTITLEMENTDATE\",\"STOCK_SUBSCRIPTION_PURCHASE\":\"SSENTITLEMENTDATE\"}"}
```

Retrieve Config from ConfigObject as:

```
    mapAsString = config.getString("AppConfig.PurchaseDates");
```

Then you can parse it as map using Gson or Jackson.